# mysql index not optimizing query

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

I have mysql MyISAM table on which I am doing a simple `select id from mytable limit 1;`. This just freezes the system.

I tried `explain select id from mytable limit 1;`. Again it freezes my system. Table demographics: 50k records, 10 mbs size, 2 indexes (primary key autoincrement), 8 columns.

I am clueless why the `explain` statement failed, as it is supposed to display the query plan, nothing else. Neither the table size is enormous nor the number of records, then why is mysql working so slow? Rather, what am I missing here?

Comment: As an aside: what is your query supposed to do?  Results will be indeterminate without an `ORDER BY` clause...

Comment: @eggyal Lets make it `order by id desc`. But this query too freezes. I have another table will just 100 records in it and it works.

Comment: Whilst one connection is running such a frozen query, what does another connection show for that connection under `SHOW PROCESSLIST`?

Comment: Hmm... with a `limit 1` it should return "instantly", index or not... something *else* is likely broken. (Event a 50k result set without a view operation should start streaming right away -- and not "freeze the system".)

Comment: +1 eggyal, you pointed me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due a waiting state on mytable. [eggyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623041/eggyal) gave me the clue to use `show processlist`. It showed:

```
+-----+---------+-----------------+----------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User    | Host            | db             | Command | Time | State                           | Info                                               |
+-----+---------+-----------------+----------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 349 | root    | localhost:56612 | mydb           | Query   | 3582 | Waiting for table metadata lock | ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD INDEX(`fk_to_02`) |
```

I planted a `kill 349` to terminate that wait chain, and now the explain statement works as expected.